# Spark - How to create new RDDs within map()? (SparkContext is null for Executors)

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, mongodb-query

I have the following application which utilizes a connection to MongoDB via the MongoDB Spark Connector. My code crashes because SparkContext is null for the Executors. Basically I am reading out data from MongoDB, process this data which results in additional queries that need to be sent to MongoDB. The last step is to save the data of these additional queries. The code I use:

```
    JavaMongoRDD<Document> rdd = MongoSpark.load(sc);
    JavaMongoRDD<Document> aggregatedRdd = rdd.withPipeline(...);
    JavaPairRDD<String, Document> pairRdd = aggregatedRdd
            .mapToPair((document) -> new Tuple2(document.get("_id"), document));
    JavaPairRDD<String, List<Document>> mergedRdd = pairRdd.aggregateByKey(new LinkedList<Document>(),
            combineFunction, mergeFunction);

    JavaRDD<Tuple2<String, List<Tuple2<Date, Date>>>> dateRdd = mergedRdd.map(...);

    //at this point dateRdd contains key/value pairs of:
    //Key: a MongoDB document ID (String)
    //Value: List of Tuple<Date, Date> which are date ranges (start time and end time). 

    //For each of that date ranges I want to retrieve the data out of MongoDB
    //and, for now, I just want to save that data

    dateRdd.foreachPartition(new VoidFunction<Iterator<Tuple2<String, List<Tuple2<Date, Date>>>>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Iterator<Tuple2<String, List<Tuple2<Date, Date>>>> partitionIterator) throws Exception {
            for (; partitionIterator.hasNext(); ) {
                Tuple2<String, List<Tuple2<Date, Date>>> tuple = partitionIterator.next();
                String fileName = tuple._1;
                List<Tuple2<Date, Date>> dateRanges = tuple._2;

                for (Tuple2<Date, Date> dateRange : dateRanges) {
                    Date startDate = dateRange._1;
                    Date endDate = dateRange._2;

                    Document aggregationDoc = Document.parse("{ $match: { ts: {$lt: new Date(" + startDate.getTime()
                            + "), $gt: new Date(" + endDate.getTime() + ")}, root_document: \"" + fileName
                            + "\", signals: { $elemMatch: { signal: \"SomeValue\" } } } }");


                    //this call will use the initial MongoSpark rdd with the aggregation pipeline that just got created.
                    //this will get sent to MongoDB 
                    JavaMongoRDD<Document> filteredSignalRdd = rdd.withPipeline(Arrays.asList(aggregationDoc));

                    String outputFileName = String.format("output_data_%s_%d-%d", fileName,
                            startDate.getTime(), endDate.getTime());
                    filteredSignalRdd.saveAsTextFile(outputFileName);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

The exception I get is:

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 23 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 23.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 501, hadoopb24): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: RDD transformation requires a non-null SparkContext.
Unfortunately SparkContext in this MongoRDD is null.
This can happen after MongoRDD has been deserialized.
SparkContext is not Serializable, therefore it deserializes to null.
RDD transformations are not allowed inside lambdas used in other RDD transformations.
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:233)
    at com.mongodb.spark.rdd.MongoRDD.checkSparkContext(MongoRDD.scala:170)
    at com.mongodb.spark.rdd.MongoRDD.copy(MongoRDD.scala:126)
    at com.mongodb.spark.rdd.MongoRDD.withPipeline(MongoRDD.scala:116)
    at com.mongodb.spark.rdd.api.java.JavaMongoRDD.withPipeline(JavaMongoRDD.scala:46)
```

What I expected from my application is illustrated in this figure:
[image]

What is the issue here, how can I achieve this "nested", async creation of new RDDs?

How can I access the MongoSpark "context" within the executors? The MongoSpark library needs access to the SparkContext, which is not available in the executors.

Do I need to bring all data to the driver again and then let the driver send out new calls to the MongoSpark "context"? I can see how this might work, but this would need to be done async, i.e. whenever a partition finishes to process data and has a `<String, Tuple<Date,Date>>` ready, push it to the driver and let him start off the new query. How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected and won't change. Spark doesn't support:

- nested RDDs.
- nested transformations.
- nested actions.
- accessing context or session from action / transformations.

In this case you can probably use standard Mongo Client.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand you right. Are you suggesting to have each executor use the standard Mongo Client in the `foreachPartition` part -- or better in a `mapPartitions` and then return the new loaded data so I can work with it afterwards?

Comment: Yes, if you need a query based on the data you already have in Spark.

Comment: I guess I should create one MongoDB connection per executor environment then. Do you have an example of setting a variable that is local to the executor? I think I should not do one connection to the sharded cluster per partition because I could have a lot of partitions. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40633892/spark-how-to-create-a-variable-that-is-different-for-each-executor-environment

Comment: I am not familiar with Mongo / Java. If client is thread safe or provides connection pools you can try with singleton. It would be shared between all executor threads. Otherwise `rdd,mapPartitions(iter => { createClient; procesIterWithClient})`