# Spark - How to create a variable that is different for each executor context?

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark

My Spark application launches several executors. 
I have several partitions that get spread over my executors.

When using map() on these partitions, I want to use a MongoDB connection ([MongoDB Java Driver](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/java/)) and query more data from there, process this data and return it as the output of the map() function.

I want to create one connection per executor.
Each partition should then access this executor-local variable and use it to query the data.

Establishing a connection for each partition is probably not a good idea. Broadcasting the connection won't work either because it is not serializable (I think?).

To sum it up:

- How to create a variable that is different for each executor context?

Comment: did you use map() or mapPartitions()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`MongoConnector`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/mongodb/spark/MongoConnector.scala).

It will handle creating a collection and is backed by a cache that efficiently handles the shutdown of any MongoClients.  It is serialisable so it can be a broadcast and it can take options, a readConfig or the Spark context to configure where to connect to.

`MongoConnector` uses the loan pattern to handle reference management of the underlying connection to MongoDB and allows access at the `MongoClient`, `MongoDatabase` or the `MongoCollection` level.